# Copying the standard HTML design of function descriptions in the Function editor

Tags: qgis, html, qgis-custom-function

I am creating my own function in the function editor and want to copy the HTML design of the standard function description, but I can't find it anywhere.

Where can I find it?

**UPDATE:**
I found a description of the `area` function in the [QGIS repository](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/f32725658f205af4ac9718d3a3b74f13eaa98d3e/resources/function_help/json/area), and it contains a description that corresponds exactly to the screenshot below. Apparently this description is somehow handled separately to give the description a standard style.

**UPDATE 2:**
It looks like I found the right piece of [code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/f5be851a7c94fff26b3abd16b2d1d030052a1dca/src/core/expression/qgsexpression.cpp) that handles the JSON data for the HTML style I want.

[image]

Comment: Using [`QgsExpression::helpText`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/cf1ffdaaa1c7c35ecd5628ce7bf777d4c1cf69ac/src/core/expression/qgsexpression.cpp#L533) seems the [way to go](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338835/proper-styling-of-help-text-in-custom-functions-qgsfunction-html-code) to identify the html elements and styles applied to each section. On the other hand, handling the whole style as suggested by @Ian Turton ensures the display won't be affected by an eventual change in the code base (like removing/renaming a css class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick hack, you can copy the description from one standard function and paste it into a custom function using online HTML editors like [this](https://wordtohtml.net) one.

[image]

Here is the HTML code (unfortunately, it is very large and unreadable):

```
    <span style=" font-family:'Lato,Open Sans,Lucida Grande,Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif'; color:#000000;">Returns the area of a geometry polygon object. Calculations are always planimetric in the Spatial Reference System (SRS) of this geometry, and the units of the returned area will match the units for the SRS. This differs from the calculations performed by the $area function, which will perform ellipsoidal calculations based on the project&apos;s ellipsoid and area unit settings.</span>
    <p style=" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#f6f6f6;"><span style=" font-family:'Lato,Open Sans,Lucida Grande,Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif'; font-size:medium; font-weight:600; color:#93b023; background-color:#f6f6f6;">Syntax</span></p>
    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><span style=" font-family:'Lato,Open Sans,Lucida Grande,Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif'; font-weight:600; color:#0a6099;">area</span><span style=" font-family:'Courier New'; color:#000000;">(</span><span style=" font-family:'monospace'; font-style:italic; color:#bf0c0c;">geometry</span><span style=" font-family:'Courier New'; color:#000000;">)</span></p>
    <p style=" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#f6f6f6;"><span style=" font-family:'Lato,Open Sans,Lucida Grande,Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif'; font-size:medium; font-weight:600; color:#93b023; background-color:#f6f6f6;">Arguments</span></p>
    <p style="-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:'Lato,Open Sans,Lucida Grande,Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif'; color:#000000;"><br></p>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style=" padding-right:10;">
                    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><span style=" font-family:'monospace'; font-style:italic; color:#bf0c0c;">geometry</span></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><span style=" font-family:'Lato,Open Sans,Lucida Grande,Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif'; color:#000000;">polygon geometry object</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p style=" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#f6f6f6;"><span style=" font-family:'Lato,Open Sans,Lucida Grande,Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif'; font-size:medium; font-weight:600; color:#93b023; background-color:#f6f6f6;">Examples</span></p>
    <ul style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; -qt-list-indent: 1;">
        <li style=" font-family:'Lato,Open Sans,Lucida Grande,Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif'; color:#000000;"><span style=" font-family:'Courier New';">area(geom_from_wkt(&apos;POLYGON((0 0, 4 0, 4 2, 0 2, 0 0))&apos;))</span> &rarr; <span style=" font-family:'Courier New';">8.0</span></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find it in the expression's code, the easiest way to find an example is to look in your QGIS profile directory (from the `Settings->User Profiles` menu) and look at one that you like the layout of.

[image]

and then look in the matching python file:

```
from qgis.core import qgsfunction,QgsExpressionContextUtils,QgsExpression,QgsProject,QgsPoint,QgsGeometry
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False, referencedColumns=[])
def make_zigzagline(geom,dist,offset,feature,parent):
    """
    <style>
    span { color: red }

    </style>
    <h2>converts a linestring to a zig-zag line</h2>

    make_zigzagline(<span>geometry</span>,<span>distance(s)</span>,<span>offset</span>)<br/>

    <table>
        <tr><td><span>geometry</span></td><td>linestring geometry</td></tr>
        <tr><td><span>distance(s)</span></td><td>linear point distances (single number or a string of comma separated numbers)</td></tr>
        <tr><td><span>offset</span></td><td>perpendicular offset</td></tr>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    Examples:
    <ul>
        <li>make_zigzagline($geometry,'15,30',15) -> zig-zag line</li>
        <li>make_zigzagline($geometry,15,15) -> zig-zag line</li>
    </ul>

    Use smooth function to create wavelines:<br/><br/>
    Example:
    <ul><li>smooth(make_zigzagline($geometry,'15,30',15),3)</li></ul>
    """

    if not type(dist) is str:
        dist = str(dist)
```

To see how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know how to access the description of the functions I created. I would like to copy the template of a standard function. The template in your answer is similar to the standard function template, but still slightly different. See my screenshot in the question.

Comment: it's just <h2>, <h3>'s etc. I'm not sure there is a "standard" template

Comment: It turned out to be not so easy to create a fully matching pattern: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/391172/35561